# SWIG typemap for STL map of pointers to a class

Tags: python, c++, pointers, stl, swig

I'm trying to SWIG wrap (version 3) a C++ STL map of int to pointers of a class, to Python 3:

**example.h**

```
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Test{};

class Example{
public:
    map<int,Test*> my_map;
    Example() 
    {
        int a=0;
        Test *b = new Test();
        this->my_map[a] = b;
    }
};
```

**example.i**

```
%module example

%{
     #include "example.h"
%}

using namespace std;

%typemap(out) map<int,Test*> {
  $result = PyDict_New();

  map<int,Test*>::iterator iter;
  Test* theVal;
  int theKey;

  for (iter = $1.begin(); iter != $1.end(); ++iter) {
    theKey = iter->first;
    theVal = iter->second;
    PyObject *value = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(theVal), SWIGTYPE_p_Test, 0);
    PyDict_SetItem($result, PyInt_FromLong(theKey), value);
  }
};

class Test{};

class Example{
public:
  map<int,Test*> my_map;
};
```

No errors, but now in Python 3, running

```
import example
t = example.Example()
t.my_map
```

returns

```
<Swig Object of type 'map< int,Test * > *' at 0x10135e7b0>
```

instead of a dictionary. It also has a pointer to a map, rather than a map. How do I write a correct `%typemap` to convert the STL map into a Python 3 dictionary?

I have been able to do this for maps of e.g. int to int - it is the pointer to a class that is giving me trouble.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me get the relevant entry from the SWIG manual for you... [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_structure_data_members)

This tells you that the member variable `my_map` is accessed via a getter that SWIG generates, which returns a `map<int,Test*> *` (or reference, if you give the `%naturalvar` directive). Therefore, your out typemap must be written to handle a `map<int,Test*> *` instead of a `map<int,Test*>`.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that is the obvious answer. Why does the getter return a pointer, rather than the object? For example, if we instead SWIG wrap a function that returns a map `map<int,Test*> my_function();`, then SWIG will return a `map<int,Test*>` as desired instead of the `map<int,Test*>*`.

Comment: A getter returns a pointer to the member object to avoid having to make a copy. If it returned by value instead, a copy of the member object would be made and returned. This is also discussed in the SWIG manual under the above link.